# Low Rider Challenge

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

While playing GTA: San Andreas today, I got to the [Low Rider Challenge](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas/Lowrider_Challenge). It's seemingly impossible to beat this, as no matter how well I do, my opponent seems to one up me. I don't particularly care how I beat it - I just want to get to the next mission. How can I possibly accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That was one of my favorite ways to make some cash.

Only advice, make sure that as the directions come along the screen that you hit AS they pass through the Circle. Not before, not after... make sure you're getting "awesome"

There are actually a couple missions where this same process applies.

Comment: I lined them up right in the middle and....aced it.

Comment: I don't even have to play the video and I can remember the music.  Ugh, that music....

Answer (score 2):

> The game's timing for the rhythm sections, (especially the Lowrider
>   challenge but also when Dancing), is off by a fair amount. Even on the
>   old PS2 version running on a CRT (with little to no image
>   preprocessing), the off-beat display of the buttons in the sweet spot
>   is noticeable.
>
> From my years of playing, the beat seems to be about 0.4 of a second
>   off from the music in the Lowrider challenge, and closer to 0.2 off in
>   the Dancing sections. You need to almost ignore the beat of the music,
>   follow the incoming buttons, and press slightly after when you should.
>
> [image: Example image of when to press buttons]
>
> Normally you would push to the beat of the music, which (ideally)
>   would be represented by the middle of the blue circle. However, you
>   need to hold off *just* slightly enough to press the button as it
>   **leaves** the circle.
>
> Personally, for years I actually muted the game during the Lowrider
>   challenge as I found it that distracting, it took me a while to be
>   able to pass with the music on.
>
> As always, practice makes perfect, so save beforehand and just repeat
>   the challenge over and over. Pattern memorization also comes into
>   play, as the buttons are in the same order every time.

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/255929/148510)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the right honourable ap_sims, I found it easier once I stopped concentrating exact position of the arrow in the circle, and just listened to the music (whatever you think of it). Press the keys on the beat. The same applies to the other dance mini games.

Comment: I was the opposite - listening to the music was throwing me off, because the beats and the movement didn't line up - the movement was always a split second behind the beat. I had to beat this mission on Mute :P