# How to circumvent game breaking bug in GTA: San Andreas (PC)

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I thought I'd give GTA: San Andreas a go, given that I haven't played it yet, and having finished GTA V, I got a copy of GTA:SA and tried to run it on my computer.

Everything seems to work fine, except for the two DDR-like missions, and in fact all the DDR-like minigames (dancing in nightclubs, etc).

The arrows slowly creep to the center (the circle) from the right, but instead of going all the way smoothly, the game seems to skip ahead at least once per second, bringing up several "missed" messages on screen. Since the arrows do not pass by the circle smoothly, the two plot-critical dance missions are not complete-able.

I have tried many different varitions on display settings, trying pretty much all available resolutuibs, with 'widescreen' on and off, 'frame limiter' on and off, and all the other settings on and off.

Nothing seems to help, though. Also, I'm kinda poking in the dark with this, because I have no idea where to even look for a solution.

Aside from this, I didn't notice any other problems with synchronization, or something.

I believe the way the arrows *should* be synchronized, is evident in this video:

(one of the few videos, where people *don't* showcase how to use a glitch to skip the mission).

This is not at all what the arrows do in my case, where the whole set of arrows on screen gets replaces by a set of new arrows, and I get several "missed" messages at once on the screen (sometimes filling the whole screen with "missed" messages).

---

**EDIT**

This error was reproducible with both the installation I made from a DVD, and by getting it from Steam.

A partial improvement can be obtained by forcing the game to be started in Windowed mode. To do this, one needs to get hold of a file called `d3d9.dll`, I got mine from a rather dubious source (some mediafire link I've found in the description of a Youtube video). That file has something to do with older versions of DirectX, but I'm no expert on that. The file needs to be placed next to the `gta_sa.exe` in the directory where GTA:SA is installed.

Anyway, the game - and especially the DDR-like minigames - become playable once resolution is set to 800x600 or less in "FULLSCREEN", i.e. 4:3 aspect ratio.

*It would be nice, if someone might shed some light on what this `d3d9.dll` file does, and a reliable - non virus infested - source for it.*

Comment: Are you running the steam version? It was updated with bug-fixes, unlike the DVD release.

Comment: nope, I have a DVD version.

Comment: It has been a long time since I played this, but remember tweaking something in the realms of DirectX to get the game running - that was on Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: Hmmm... install the game somewhere else and transfer the saves. Or send the save to a friend.

Comment: As there a serial key with the DVD?  If so, try to see if it will work on Steam to unlock the Steam version of the game.

Comment: @NBN-Alex It doesn't work.

Comment: It's difficult to find, but there seem to be other people having this sort of problem, too. I bought it on Steam just now, and it's currently installing. I wish to use my old version, though. I imagine it'll work better with mods, etc.

Comment: I just played the Steam version far enough, so I can see if the bug persists: yes it does :(

Comment: Try pressing the arrow while it's half way trough the circle. Check some videos of these missions, but i can remember that it was doing this by design. ANd pressing it being half way in the circle (or slightly before it skips for you) might just work fine, even iif it doesn't give you 100% mark on the move you still might be able to play it trough and carry on ...

Comment: If you have replicated the bug in CD and Steam versions then you should put that in the original question.  Maybe adding a screenshot too if possible.

Comment: @camelCase Well, then I guess I should make a video? A simple screenshot doesn't really reflect what's happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Low Rider Challenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39907/low-rider-challenge)

Answer (score 2):

I have never encountered the 'skipping' bug you describe, but in terms of getting 'misses' on beats, there may be another solution:

The game's timing for the rhythm sections, (especially the Lowrider challenge but also when Dancing), is off by a fair amount. Even on the old PS2 version running on a CRT (with little to no image preprocessing), the off-beat display of the buttons in the sweet spot is noticeable.

From my years of playing, the beat seems to be about 0.4 of a second off from the music in the Lowrider challenge, and closer to 0.2 off in the Dancing sections. You need to almost ignore the beat of the music, follow the incoming buttons, and press slightly after when you should.

Take this terrible MS Paint example I drew up in about 30 seconds:
[image: Example image of when to press buttons]

Normally you would push to the beat of the music, which (ideally) would be represented by the middle of the blue circle. However, you need to hold off *just* slightly enough to press the button as it **leaves** the circle.

Personally, for years I actually muted the game during the Lowrider challenge as I found it that distracting, it took me a while to be able to pass with the music on.

As always, practice makes perfect, so save beforehand and just repeat the challenge over and over. Pattern memorisation also comes into play, as the buttons are in the same order every time. So keep at it and you'll get it eventually!

Comment: Yeah, that's not the issue at all for my problem. The game skips ahead up to five arrows ahead, which simply vanish and the next set of arrows appears instantly, this happens throughout the whole mini-game. Other than that, I'm quite used to rhythm games like that. I've been playing StepMania with a keyboard for many years. I'm afraid your answer is completely non-sequitur to my questions, though :/

Comment: @polemon man, that sounds terrible, from the description in your question I thought it was only jumping a little bit :-(. I'll do some digging.   Can you confirm you're running the game with your dedicated graphics card and not a low power one like 'Intel HD Graphics?'

Comment: Fwiw I played this on a crappy laptop with just the non gaming integrated graphics, without this issue. I know that doesn't help Polemon but it might help you (or anyone ) push through to the solution. :)

Comment: I think I might've found a partial solution, or be at least on to something: The skips are smaller, when I dropped a d3d9.dll into the game directory, which forces the game to be in windowed mode. I got this file from a rather dubious source from mediafire, It's still not perfect, but it seems the skips are smaller, the lower resolution I choose. What is the native resolution of the PS2 game, that used to be released originally?

Comment: @polemon - funnily enough I looked this up for an unrelated issue the other day. The PS2 outputs at 480i 30fps for NTSC, 576i 25fps in PAL regions. So about 720x480 resolution

Comment: Yep, eventually passed the stage by setting the resolution to 800x600 and playing in windowed mode. It was still skipping ahead, but the skips were small enough so I was still withing a penalty, that was enough to pass the level.
That being said, San Andreas glitches out incredibly often: One too many times entered Pause / Menu and the game locks up. Sometimes the screen stays blank when loading a save game, sometimes mouse doesn't work (usually fixed by going once into pause menu and then resume).

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on my laptop with the arrows jumping I had during the same dancing and lowrider games. I fixed mine by changing the compatibility mode to Windows XP Service Pack 3

Answer (score 0):

There is a mod called [SilentPatch](https://gtaforums.com/topic/669045-silentpatch/) that aims to fix a bunch of game bugs that exist since the initial release. One of the fixes is the dancing minigame timings:

> Dancing minigame timings have been improved, now they do not lose accuracy over time depending on PC's uptime

Answer (score -3):

If you're running the game on a 64-bit system but playing the 32-bit version that could be to blame. If that is the case look for a patch - if you look in the disk itself sometimes they come with a 64bit patch.

Otherwise try Right-clicking on the `.exe` file (not the shortcut or autorun), go to properties and select `run it compatibility mode for 32bit.`

Also check your monitor setup. If your using a setup with progressive scan the game is likely loading certain frames ahead of time causing this glitch. Disabling progressive scan (ie setting graphics card settings to 1080i instead of 1080p may solve the issue.

Good luck.

Comment: It is a 5GHz quad core running on a GeForce 8200. The system is a native Windows XP, with 8GB of RAM (of which WinXP can only adress 3GB, to my knowledge).

Comment: You did not completely address all the issues I have cited above.I tried to be of help giving you many possible causes and solutions that may be applicable trying to be helpful.I don't deserve bad rep for tying. The use of a high performance graphics card possibly connected to a 1080p HDMI display would cause progressive scan effects to preload events which are time crucial and check the results before real-time display caught up. Resulting in the skipping frames as you described.try going to your graphics card settings and setting it manually to 1080i instead of 1080p.

Comment: As a side note windows can likely only see the 3gb ram because you are using 32bit version of xp good for compatibility for most programs. I'd recommend you look into a boot level ramdisk and load xp onto it as this will allow you to have much quicker function of everything installed on it presuming you only use standby instead of full shutdown.

Comment: You're not allowed to vandalize your answer because you got downvotes for it.  You can delete it, but changing it so it no longer answers the question is seen as vandalization.  To that end, I have rolled back your answer.

Comment: 320x480i I believe is the native formatting of old CRT TV systems